# How to load to panels a referenced node?

Tags: views, panels, 7

I have the user profile panel and I want to load in the panel a node that is referencing this user.
There is a trick to load a view in the panel,but I don't know exactly how to do this...
Can somebody help me on this?thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to add a display to your view of type "pane". Give it a descriptive title so you can find it from your Page Manager.

Then you'll create a Page Manager variant that displays on the entity (user) to which you want to attach this view. Under "content" you'll click the gear that appears in the top left, and click "add content". Select "view panes" and then select the view pane you just created.

In order to pass the node ID to the view pane, you'll go back to the view. Under "pane settings" select "argument input" and set it to "from panel argument". You'll probably want the first argument.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the answer.Still the issue is not solved.The node is not visible in the context,so as to add some fields of it to the panel.Some more suggestions?thanks

Comment: You'll also want to make sure your view has an argument for node ID defined.

Comment: The view has a relationship and an argument for the User Id(It is a node view).Is this correct?

Comment: Yes but there's a UID field for the author of the node as well, so it could be the wrong one. Without looking at your View it's hard to know.